# How to check if $\int_0^1{\frac{\ln(x)\tan(x)}{x}}$ exists?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm learning for an exam in calculus and I encountered a question to check if the following integral exists: $$\int_0^1{\frac{\ln(x)\tan(x)}{x}}$$I tried comparing it to $\frac{1}{x}$ but I get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{|\frac{\ln(x)\tan(x)}{x}|}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\ln(x)\tan(x)}$$ and I don't know how to calculate this limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {\tan x} x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ and $|\ln x|$ is integrable on $(0,1)$. Hence the integral is convergent.

Comment: so I need to compare this integral to $|\ln(x)|$?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes. In fact we can show that $\frac 1 2 x \leq {\tan x}  \leq x$ for $0<x<1$ and you can compare the given  integral with that of $-\ln x \equiv |ln x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$\lim_{x\to0}\log(x)\tan(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\log(x)x\frac{\tan(x)}x$$and that therefore, since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}x=1$, all you have to do is to compute the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\log(x)x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(x)}{\frac1x}.$$

Comment: by L'Hopital rule it's 0 so it doesn't help as $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}$ is divergent.